# How to remove beginning of filename in PHP?

Tags: php, gallery, jssor

I'm making a gallery in jssor and the slides are made by reading a directory and writing the div for every image using a PHP script. Under the image a caption is displayed with the name of the artist (this is always the same) followed by the file name without the extension.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?

$dir = 'Photo/Paintings';
$files = scandir($dir);
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        echo '<div>
                <img u="image" style="max-height:460px;" src="Photo/Paintings/'.$file.'" />
               <img u="thumb" src="Photo/Paintings/'.$file.'" />';
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);
            echo '<div u="caption" style="position: absolute; top: 470px; left: 0px; height: 10px; text-align: center;">
                      ARTISTX - '.$withoutExt.'
              </div>
        </div>';
    }
}

?>
```

These images should be in a particular order, so my idea was to add a number at the beginning of every filename like so `#5-Picture of tree.jpg`. My question is, how do I remove this `#5` part from being displayed in the caption as well?

Alternatively, is there a better way to determine the order of these files? I realize now my idea wouldn't even work very well since #1 would alphabetically be followed by #11 and #12 instead of #2. I could maybe work around this by using a combination with letters 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only take effect if the file name actually starts with a number:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\\d+-/', null, $fileName);
```

Files which do not start with `#{number}-` will not be affected by this tailoring process.

For your sorting problem. Put a filling `0` before. So use `01`, `02`, ... and so on up to `99`.

By the way. Don't use short PHP tags. Always use `<?php` at the beginning of a PHP block.

Comment: Homerun! The 0 prefix is genius, how did I not think of that :) Using a hashtag broke the link (maybe it's a Linux server thing?). I can just use the 0 as the beginning reference for the string like so: $str = preg_replace('/^0\\d+-/', null, $fileName);

Comment: No you can't. Then `11` does not get matched by the regex. only `011`. Just use the regex provided as is by me.

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured. I can always use a 3 digit prefix 001, 011 and so forth.

Comment: Even a three digit prefix gets cached by my regex. Actually any numeric prefix of any length gets catched.

Comment: I understand, but I can't use the #-symbol in a filename. My Linux server refuses to read and display it in the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You can get only a part of the string:

```
$str = substr($str, 3);
```

Or you delete the part before the `-` explicit:

```
$ex = explode("-", $str);
unset($ex[0]);
$str = implode("-", $ex);
```

Second method is better if the first part can have more than 3 characters.

> Alternatively, is there a better way to determine the order of these files? I realize now my idea wouldn't even work very well since #1 would alphabetically be followed by #11 and #12 instead of #2. I could maybe work around this by using a combination with letters 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, etc.

Use this:

```
$myFiles = Array();
foreach($files as $file){
  // ...
  $myFiles[str_replace("#", "", explode("-", $file)[0]))] = $file;
}
ksort($myFiles);

foreach($myFiles as $file){
  // display
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question you don't have to change to 1A, 2B... there is sort like natsort [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)